# How to use the placeholders in tensoflow to take an arbitrary matrix?

Tags: matrix, tensorflow

I am new to using Tensorflow.
I have two matrices that I want to take as input:
[image]

and my output matrix is as such:

[image]
When I do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
matrix1 = tf.placeholder();
matrix2 = tf.placeholder();
output_matrix = tf.placeholder();
```

is that enough? I do not know how I can define the shape of the matrix and the dtype if the matrices are arbitrary?

Comment: Not sure what your question really is, how to specify a dynamic shape or how to feed a matrix?

Comment: I think both. I am new to TensorFlow and want to know how I would model this.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to leave the shape unspecified for a placeholder; you'll be able to feed anything that works with the downstream ops. Dtype will default to `float32`. But you do need to specify a sequence of transformations which go from your inputs (placeholders) to your outputs (not placeholders); see https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/mechanics#build_the_graph.

If it's easier, you can also get started with [eager execution](https://research.googleblog.com/2017/10/eager-execution-imperative-define-by.html), then switch to graph building later.